# gdb printing <incomplete type> with incomplete enum class declaration

Tags: c++, gdb

I've been dipping my toes in C++, and found a surprising behavior of gdb. I'm wondering if it is the expected behavior, or if I messed something up.

```cpp
enum class Foo;
struct Bar { Foo a; int b; };
enum class Foo { A, B, C };

int main() {
    auto a = Foo::A;
    auto b = Bar{ Foo::A, 1 };
}
```

built with gcc 7.5.0 (with the `-g` option) and ran with gdb 8.1.1
When trying to print the value of a, or b.a, the result is `<incomplete type>`.
This doesn't happen if the struct declaration is not between the two enumeration declaration, or if the enumeration is fully declared once.

For the practical reason why I tried this, I had a header file containing a relatively big class declaration with some of its member being enumeration types. I felt have the full declaration of the enumerations after the class declaration was cleaner, and decided to partially declare them.

Is there something I can do to access the variable information in gdb while still doing these partial declarations, or is fully declaring my enumerations the only way.

Theses similar questions

- [gdb class is incomplete type until I set breakpoint in class constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41068557/gdb-class-is-incomplete-type-until-i-set-breakpoint-in-class-constructor)
- [How to print <incomplete type> variable in gdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232744/how-to-print-incomplete-type-variable-in-gdb)
- [GDB incomplete type when having C++ virtual function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29494132/gdb-incomplete-type-when-having-c-virtual-function)

do not concern my situation, since I have no trouble accessing the type information if the enumeration is only fully declared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `g++ (Debian 11.2.0-10) 11.2.0` and GDB-10.0:

```
7           auto b = Bar{ Foo::A, 1 };
(gdb) p a
$1 = Foo::A
(gdb) n
8       }
(gdb) p b
$2 = {a = Foo::A, b = 1}
```

> built with gcc 7.5.0 (with the -g option) and ran with gdb 8.1.1

These are pretty ancient.

> Is there something I can do

I suggest trying latest released GDB (easy to build from source), and if that doesn't help, latest GCC.